# discord. py on_raw_reaction_add() expects 'for'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a Syntax Error at the following code:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content == "channel id":
        print("Channel Id von " + message.channel.name + ": " + str(message.channel.id)

async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    #some code
```

I have the problem even if I just print something.

The Error is between the 'async' and the 'def'. At the Problems tab at PyCharm it says that a 'for' is expected at this line.

I've already read the documantaion and viewed som examples but i didn't found something about this problem.

**Update**

I found out that the keyword 'async' belongs to an if-statement before. I changed it above. (I still don't know how to fix this)

Comment: Please add more code, maybe you're missing a closing parenthesis in the lines above? Or a missing colon?

Comment: Often if an error message doesn't make sense (as in referring to something that simply isn't true) then it means there's an issue a little earlier and the parser hit the line it complained about before it realised something wasn't right.

Comment: Your error is the line before that, check your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just forgot a bracket at the `print()` function.

It has to be like this:

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content == "channel id":
        print("Channel Id von " + message.channel.name + ": " + str(message.channel.id))

async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    #some code
```